# How to find regulations specified in the US Code?

Tags: united-states, regulations

How does one find regulations that are specified by the United States Code?  For example, [22 USC § 288b](http://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title22-section288b&num=0&edition=prelim) says:

> #### §288b. Baggage and effects of officers and employees exempted from customs duties and internal revenue taxes
>
> Pursuant to regulations prescribed by the Commissioner of U.S. Customs and Border Protection with the approval of the Secretary of the Treasury, the baggage and effects of alien officers and employees of international organizations, or of aliens designated by foreign governments to serve as their representatives in or to such organizations, or of the families, suites, and servants of such officers, employees, or representatives shall be admitted (when imported in connection with the arrival of the owner) free of customs duties and free of internal-revenue taxes imposed upon or by reason of importation.

I am unable to locate any relevant "regulations prescribed by the Commissioner of U.S. Customs and Border Protection with the approval of the Secretary of the Treasury" in the [Code of Federal Regulations](http://www.ecfr.gov/); do they exist, and, if so, where?

A general answer to the question is obviously preferable, but if someone is able to find the specific regulations in the example without being able to answer the general question, that is also helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an index](http://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/cfr/front/titles.html), identifying what agencies have regulations in each chapter.

[Title 19, Chapter I](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=64c8c390576130ebad9982c95fbaf53d&c=ecfr&tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title19/19cfrv1_02.tpl) contains regulations from the "Bureau of Customs and Border Protection".

[19 CFR 148.87](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=2cc890476664b4ccf779946f61e7ae72&mc=true&node=se19.2.148_187&rgn=div8) self-identifies as implementing the regulations referred to in 22 USC 288b.

I use combinations of the following to help me find regulations associated with a particular statute:

- the statute citation (e.g. 22 USC 288b, or 22 USC 288)
- the delegated agency (e.g. Customs and Border Protection)
- the phrase "implementing regulation"
- the phrase "notice and comment"
- the phrase "federal register"

You can also search the [Federal Register](https://www.federalregister.gov/) directly, but you have to use different variants of the US Code citation (22 USC 288b, 22 U.S.C. 288, 22 USC §288, etc.).